# Copy and paste data from multiple worksheets to a master workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy and paste the data from multiple worksheet to master workbook, but I need to open all workbook before copying the data

```
''This one I use for the opening the documents 

    ScanWBName = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        ("CSV (*.csv),*.csv", , "Select the " & FirstChart & " Scan File")
    If ScanWBName = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
''This one I used for the selecting all the datas in multiple worksheet 
lLastRow = Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

I wrote this one, but my problem is that I need to close all the files after opening it.

The major problem

1. While copying I need to copy everything that is in the file.
2. After pasting the data again I need to start with empty cell in the master workbook after the next file

Comment: Sorry, but for me it's complete unclear what you're asking

Comment: I need to copy the file last row and last coulmn and paste to anthoer workbook

Comment: I need to paste the data and again start to paste the data after the last row

Comment: And what prevents you to do so?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done MUCH easier.  Download and install the AddIn from the link below and follow the (very intuitive prompts).

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]